# Mariadb host works on “localhost” but not IP alternative - 127.0.0.1

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to connect to my database through an ash tunnel using sequel pro but it is not working and forces me to use `127.0.0.1` when entering "localhost" which leads to the problem where if I run on the command line:

```
 mysql --host "localhost"
```

It works

If I run:

```
 mysql --host "127.0.0.1"
```

I get the access denied error:

> ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

What is going on?

---

I have tried:
`update user set host='%' where host='localhost'`
but this does not work.

Comment: You need to grant remote access. Anything over TCP/IP is considered "remote".

Comment: You get EXACTLY which error. Please dont summarise error messages

Comment: Not come across an `ash` tunnel before. Do you mean `SSH`

Comment: Its also useful if you hang around for a few minutes after asking a question to answer any questions, specially as your question is a little vague

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry about that

Comment: @RiggsFolly please see my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many SQL servers have two or more different user entries for every user that might come in via either localhost or remote. (127.0.0.1 counts as remote).

For example, for the root user, you might have these three user entries.

```
 CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY REDACTED;
 CREATE USER 'root'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY REDACTED;
 CREATE USER 'root'@'%.example.com' IDENTIFIED BY REDACTED;
```

There's nothing much special about the name `root` except that it has been granted a lot of privileges when your MySQL was installed. You need to grant the same privileges to the other versions of `root`@whatever you create.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new user:

```
CREATE USER 'non-root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123';
```

and then granted them all the same privileges:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'non-root'@'localhost';
```

and then deleted root and renamed `non-root` to `root`

and now it finally works.